# Telerik MVC Grid sever binding with ajax editing

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I have an application that is making extensive use of telerik controls and am looking for an example/demo of Telerik MVC grid that uses server binding to display the initial grid and then allow inline editing using ajax. I have a selection that is returning a lot of data and erroring out at the maxJsonLength. The code to configure the grid would be helpful and I should be able to fiigure out the rest. I think I saw an example somewhere of an ajax bound grid that used server binding for the initial load but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Having a server-side bound grid with ajax editing is possible. However you first need to solve the maxJsonLength problem. The grid needs to serialize the first page of data (which is initially displayed server-side) as JSON so it can be then edited on the client-side. It seems that you are serializing too much data which hits the maxJsonLength limit. I can think of two ways to deal with this:

1. Use a ViewModel and serialize only the properties which are bound to the grid. This will reduce the total JSON size.
2. Increase the maxJsonLength. This however is not easy as setting it from web.config does not work in ASP.NET MVC. You need to create a custom JsonResult object with its own JsonSerializer. [This](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/using-custom-jsonresult-with-ajax-bound-grid.aspx) code library project shows how.

Answer (score -3):

You have mentioned Telerik in your title but not in main question, so I assume that you are okay with other grid controls.
In that case you can try Jq grid, it's very flexible and easy to use. I have been using it for some time now and find it very useful.
For your particular case see below link

http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: Telerik is deeply embedded in our apps and we like them so we're not likely to change at this time.